# How do I use Selenium and Java to get the options available from a drop down box?

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to use Selenium to retrieve all the car makes from the Autotrader website. There is a drop-down box that changes depending on which cars are available for sale at a given time.

I have tried many of the solutions listed on stackoverflow, but my code doesn't return anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my code...

```
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;


public class AutotraderScraper {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {

        WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();

        // Visit autotrader website
        driver.get("http://www.autotrader.co.uk/");

        // Look for car make box
        Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("searchVehiclesMake")));

        // Get all options
        List<WebElement> allOptions = select.getOptions();

        // Iterate through available options
        java.util.Iterator<WebElement> i = allOptions.iterator();

        // Print options
        while(i.hasNext()) {
            WebElement row = i.next();
            System.out.println("Found an option!");
            System.out.println(row.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a Firefox or Chrome webdriver instead?

Comment: No I haven't, would you recommend it?

Comment: It can help identifying the culprit, please try.

Comment: I'll certainly give it a try and let you know. I'm still interested to hear if anyone can help with a Selenium solution too.

Comment: Nono, I mean this would still be a selenium-specific solution. I just suggest to try out other drivers instead of the HTMLUnit.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it works! I can't believe it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a duplicate id and is being used in two different places of this page.
[image]

I suggest you use `xpath` to find the `select element` The following `xpath` can be used

```
//h1[.='Find new & used cars']/..//*[@id='searchVehiclesMake']
```

Target element in Find new & used cars section

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm new to web applications, and I'm afraid I don't fully understand your comment. Could you please explain, or show me some example code?

Comment: You are welcome! please replace `Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("searchVehiclesMake")));
` with `Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h1[.='Find new & used cars']/..//*[@id='searchVehiclesMake']"))); and that will only return the element 
` you may want. See my second attachment

Comment: Is that the element you want on the second screenshot?

Comment: Thanks, that builds and runs fine, but it still doesn't return any values. Any ideas?

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: There is no exception, but I don't get any prints. For some reason my print statements are never being executed. I presume this is due to the 'AllOptions' list being empty?

Comment: OK You may need to use `implicit wait` and let the elements to load on the page. Try adding `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`. Something like `WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(); driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

Comment: Really appreciate all your help! I tried the implicit wait right after List<WebElement> allOptions = select.getOptions(); , but I still get nothing.

Comment: No I said use it after `WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();` because `implicit wait` is tied to the driver instance and you want to use it before start finding the elements

Comment: Try it with webdriver instead of htmlunit driver as alexce suggested